# created stacked pixel grid to represent a count

Tags: css, canvas, responsive-design

I'm creating a pixel grid to represent a count (see image) and wondering what's the best way to go about it.

[image: pixel count]

These tiles will need to be responsive (1px, 2px, 4px). I could build a super large sprite that contains all 196 combinations that is @4X so it scales perfectly to 2px and 1px and then build a css class...

```
<div class="pixel-block c-000"></div>
<div class="pixel-block c-001"></div>
```

...there has to be a better way?

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: How will you be determining when a block/pixel is in an active or default state? I would think your best course of action here would be pure HTML/CSS to build each block/pixel. That is, if I'm understanding correctly.

Comment: the count will be fed from the database, so I'll insert the numeric returned into the class (c-001, c-002, c-003 etc). These blocks will be on 'cards' so there will be maybe ~50 per page.

Comment: If you do not want to use JavaScript, why don't you assign one of the two (pixel-on / pixel-off) classes in the backend to the appropriate div? In that case you would not have to generate such a massive css with hundreds of classes...

Comment: Yes, I will do that - but that will still rely on the image sprite. Not opposed to using JS...

Comment: @JamieTaylor, I don't think you need a sprite at all. Do you need the grid to be filled the way it is illustrated? That is, bottom left to upper left moving to the right after a column is filled?

Comment: yes, just the way it's illustrated - eg; 0, 5, 34, 196

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a example of how it can be done without using a sprite with the 196 combinations, just a grid image and CSS.

The idea is simple:

- Have a container that will hold:

  - The grid image (on top)
  - A "big" bar that will cover the whole height of the container.
  - A "small" bar that will cover only the remainder.
- The "big bar" will have a width equal to the (count value / 14) * width of the hole in the grid.
- The "low bar" will have a height equal to (count value % 14) * height of the hole in the grid.

I used a grid with 3px holes (2px + 1px separation), and the `data-` attributes to set the values of the count, and an indicator for the big bar (count / 14) and low bar (count % 14).

Here is a demo:

```css
.box {
    border:1px solid #6699aa;
    width:43px;
    height:43px;
    position:relative;
    background:#aaccff;
    overflow:hidden;
    display:inline-block;
}

.grid { background:url(http://i.imgur.com/w0jBLzK.png) no-repeat top left;
    width:43px;
    height:43px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:3;
}

.bigbar {
    height:43px;
    width:0px;
    background:black;
    z-index:2;
    float:left;
}

.lowbar {
    float:left;
    width:3px;
    height:0px;
    position:relative;
    background:black;
}

.box[data-big="1"] .bigbar { width:3px; }
.box[data-big="2"] .bigbar { width:6px; }
.box[data-big="3"] .bigbar { width:9px; }
.box[data-big="4"] .bigbar { width:12px; }
.box[data-big="5"] .bigbar { width:15px; }
.box[data-big="6"] .bigbar { width:18px; }
.box[data-big="7"] .bigbar { width:21px; }
.box[data-big="8"] .bigbar { width:24px; }
.box[data-big="9"] .bigbar { width:27px; }
.box[data-big="10"] .bigbar { width:30px; }
.box[data-big="11"] .bigbar { width:33px; }
.box[data-big="12"] .bigbar { width:36px; }
.box[data-big="13"] .bigbar { width:39px; }
.box[data-big="14"] .bigbar { width:42px; }

.box[data-low="1"] .lowbar { height:3px; margin-top:39px; }
.box[data-low="2"] .lowbar { height:6px; margin-top:36px; }
.box[data-low="3"] .lowbar { height:9px; margin-top:33px; }
.box[data-low="4"] .lowbar { height:12px; margin-top:30px; }
.box[data-low="5"] .lowbar { height:15px; margin-top:27px; }
.box[data-low="6"] .lowbar { height:18px; margin-top:24px; }
.box[data-low="7"] .lowbar { height:21px; margin-top:21px; }
.box[data-low="8"] .lowbar { height:24px; margin-top:18px; }
.box[data-low="9"] .lowbar { height:27px; margin-top:15px; }
.box[data-low="10"] .lowbar { height:30px; margin-top:12px; }
.box[data-low="11"] .lowbar { height:33px; margin-top:9px; }
.box[data-low="12"] .lowbar { height:36px; margin-top:6px; }
.box[data-low="13"] .lowbar { height:39px; margin-top:3px; }
.box[data-low="14"] .lowbar { height:42px; margin-top:0px; }
```

```html
<div class="box" data-count="0" data-big="0" data-low="0">
    <div class="grid"></div>
    <div class="bigbar"></div>
    <div class="lowbar"></div>
</div>

<div class="box" data-count="5" data-big="0" data-low="5">
    <div class="grid"></div>
    <div class="bigbar"></div>
    <div class="lowbar"></div>
</div>

<div class="box" data-count="34" data-big="2" data-low="10">
    <div class="grid"></div>
    <div class="bigbar"></div>
    <div class="lowbar"></div>
</div>

<div class="box" data-count="196" data-big="14" data-low="0">
    <div class="grid"></div>
    <div class="bigbar"></div>
    <div class="lowbar"></div>
</div>
```